# Shell is not listed in /etc/shells, when it is

Tags: shell

I must be missing something simple here, because I am trying to make a user's default shell "lshell" for limited access. I try to set the shell with the command `chsh -s /usr/bin/lshell user`but it errors with "Warning: "/usr/bin/lshell" is not listed in /etc/shells". I have triple checked the configuration file for /etc/shells, and it is the following:

```
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/bin/tcsh
/bin/csh
/usr/bin/lshell
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: output of od -c /etc/shells

```
0000000   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \n   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s
0000020   h  \n   /   s   b   i   n   /   n   o   l   o   g   i   n  \n
0000040   /   b   i   n   /   t   c   s   h  \n   /   b   i   n   /   c
0000060   s   h  \n   /   u   s   r   /   b   i   n   /   l   s   h   e
0000100   l   l
0000102
```

Comment: Would you post the output of `od -c /etc/shells`? Just to ensure no unwanted characters crept in.

Comment: 0000000   /   b   i   n   /   s   h  \n   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s
0000020   h  \n   /   s   b   i   n   /   n   o   l   o   g   i   n  \n
0000040   /   b   i   n   /   t   c   s   h  \n   /   b   i   n   /   c
0000060   s   h  \n   /   u   s   r   /   b   i   n   /   l   s   h   e
0000100   l   l
0000102

Comment: Don't know if that's a sufficient paste or not, let me know if that works.

Comment: Might be easier to read if you edit it into the Q

Answer (score 3):

Your `/etc/shells` misses newline at the end of file. Edit it with an editor which cares about this, like `vi`.